# knockout observable is not a function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am experimenting a bit with different ways to add methods to knockout viewmodels, and I came across an error I really don't understand.

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.foo = ko.observable(null);

    self.hasFoo = ko.computed(self.getHasFoo);
}

ko.utils.extend(ViewModel.prototype, {
    getHasFoo: function () {
        return this.foo() != null;
    },
});

var vm = new ViewModel();
```

When I run this, I get an error saying `Uncaught TypeError: this.foo is not a function`. I did a console.log on the actual value of this.foo, and it was indeed `undefined`. I really don't understand why. What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the context of the computed, this is the syntax `ko.computed(handler,scope)` see the update `this.hasFoo = ko.computed(self.getHasFoo,this);`, so now see it working in the snippet.

```js
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    this.foo = ko.observable(null);
    this.hasFoo = ko.computed(self.getHasFoo,this);
}

ko.utils.extend(ViewModel.prototype, {
    getHasFoo: function () {
         return this.foo();
    },
});

var vm = new ViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(vm)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input type="text" data-bind="textInput: foo"/>

<span data-bind="visible: hasFoo"> Has FOO!! </span>
```

> ### Managing ‘this’

> The second parameter to ko.computed (the bit where we passed this in the above example) defines the value of this when evaluating the computed observable. Without passing it in, it would not have been possible to refer to this.firstName() or this.lastName(). Experienced JavaScript coders will regard this as obvious, but if you’re still getting to know JavaScript it might seem strange. (Languages like C# and Java never expect the programmer to set a value for this, but JavaScript does, because its functions themselves aren’t part of any object by default.)

> Ref. [KO computed observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html)

Comment: Ahhh, of course. Totally forgot about that (my main language is c# :)). I usually get away without passing 'this' to ko.computed by using the self variable in an inline function definition. I never passed a direct function reference before. Thanks!